# Prove that $f(x)=2x-L\cos(Lx)$ has only one root in range $x\in [-1, 1]$ when $L \in [0, \pi/2]$

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Prove that $f(x)=2x-L\cos(Lx)$ has only one root in range $x\in [-1, 1]$ when $L \in [0, \pi/2]$

It's simple to show that it has at least one root using Intermediate value theorem, but I find it difficult to show that it has only one root.

Comment: is that $\;\cos LX\;$ ? Because you wrote twice $\;coxLX\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, of course, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x<0$ both terms in $f$ are negative, so that there can be no root in $[-1,0]$. If $x>\frac L2$, the first term dominates the second, as $\cos u\le 1$. Thus the roots can only occur inside $(0,\frac\pi4]$. On this interval $f'(x)=2+L^2\sin(Lx)$ is positive, so that $f$ is monotonous on this interval and can only have one root there and thus in the whole of $[-1,1]$.

[image]

Comment: Why if both terms are negative there can't be a zero in $\;[-1,0]\;$ ? We have $\;2x-L\cos Lx\;$ , **not** $\;2x+L\cos Lx\;$ . In the latter case we'd have a sum of two negative, but in the former (and original) case, we have a negative *minus* a negative = negative plus positive...

Comment: @DonAntonio : The cosine is positive on $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$, where the argument for the given interval $[-1,1]$ and for the given values of $L\in[0,\frac\pi2]$ falls into. Remember, it is a symmetric function, while the sine is the anti-symmetric one.

Comment: Of course...but it was *you* who wrote that for $\;x<0\;$ both terms in $\;f\;$ are negative...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio : Yes, both $2x$ and $-L\cos(Lx)$ are negative, so that the sum is negative and never zero.

Comment: You can say that $f'(x) = 2 + L^2sin(Lx)$ positive for all $x\in (0,1]$, Am I right? because in this case $\pi/2 >= Lx >=0$ and that is why  $1>=sin(Lx)>=0$

Comment: @Mr.OY Yes, that too is sufficient and removes some complexity. I was originally trying to isolate the root interval more using both of the cosine estimates $1-x^2/2\le \cos x\le 1$, but that does not really help further for a manual argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint (but not a solution):**

1. try drawing the graph (Desmos is a good tool; include a slider for the value $L$)
2. For any particular $L$, split into two cases: $x < 0$ and $x \ge 0$. On one of these intervals, $f$ is monotone, so the main question is why there are no double-roots in the other interval.